# Time Conversion from UTC to date sting

Tags: python, datetime, utc

Is there a way to convert UTC time to a formatted string containing the date?

I currently have a list full UTC time but I need them to be formatted as `%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S.%f` but as a string.

Comment: Have you tried: `datetime.datetime.strptime("1998-04-18 16:48:36.0",'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').strftime(%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S.%f')`?

Comment: Do you have a `timestamp`, a `datetime`, a `pandas.Timestamp` or something else?  Do you have the timezone you want to convert it to?

Comment: You should always post your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the datetime library. I have used this in the past and it works

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("1998-04-18 16:48:36.0","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").strftime("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S.%f")

'1998-04-1816:48:36.000000'
```